# DropDownListFor with color reference and name from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dropdownlistfor

I have a requirement to show color reference before project name. I need strongly typed helper and I am unable to find any link to do exactly what I need.

In all the example I found, they are using jquery with value as background color.

But I need to prepend color reference (hex code) to each item which is actually coming from db:

[image: Image here]

I am thinking of writing some htmlhelper extensions. I am really new to delegates and expression and I don't think I can write in short time I have. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: You need a jquery plugin to (a `<select>` element is rendered by the browser/OS and you have very little control over how its styled).

Comment: I understand that I need to go through jquery. But I am thinking to write an extension method because that will make my work easier to post all data.If I want to use jquery I need to make ajax call which means I have to write all the logic of dropdownlist(meaning things like hovering, showing name,passing id while posting ,selected value while editing and other stuff ).Can I achieve using jquery without missing dropdownlistfor features?

Comment: An extension method will only generate the html (which would consist of multiple elements, including `<ul>` and `<li>` for the options). You will still need to write a plugin to make it all work and respond to client side events. No one is going to write the 10+ pages of code for you. There are plenty of jquery plugins that you can use for this.

Comment: Could you provide some links if possible,PLEASE? When I look for plugins to do these kind of things, I am only getting on populating enum values or setting color value as background(mentioned earlier in question).